# ZIP64 on 32bit Windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit, zip, 32-bit

We want to include a ZIP64 functionality to our application, for which we use the [DotNetZip](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181291/DotNetZip) library.

**Do 32bit systems support ZIP64 formats, or can problems occur?**

I cannot really find anything on the internet and unfortunately do not have a 32bit machine available to test it.

EDIT: Here is a better explanation of the DotNetZip Zip64 functionality, but it also does not give me an answer: https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/aac454a2-c751-8347-c3d7-e2a617086531.htm

Comment: ZIP64 is very misleading in this case. You are asking for DotNetZip. I see no mention that it is x64 exclusive. It should run on 32 bit systems. Keep in mind that this means that you have to compile the project as x86 compatible. You may need an x86 system for this. If the compiler fails, then DotNetZip can't be used. Also keep in mind the limitations that 32bit brings, such as 3.5GB memory. You can code a protection for that in your program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Well we use the nuget package and know that the application runs on 32bit systems. So that does not seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip64 is a file format and while it's pointers and calculations *might* be more efficient on 64-bit systems it is by no means dependant on them.

Just as FAT32 filesystem support can be built in to an 8-bit microcontroller, Zip64 depends more on your compiler/interpreter than it does your CPU.

If the library you are using supports 32-bit and is capable of creating Zip64 archives then you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!